# How to compare values (integers) in an Array and store lowest value as a separate variable?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, compare

```
double lowestNum = priceArray[0]; //setting a default value just in case none of the
                                  //cases passes the if statement
    for (int i = 1; i < priceArray.length; i++) {
        if (priceArray[i] < priceArray[i - 1]) {
            lowestNum = priceArray[i]; //what I'm trying to do is rewrite this
                                          //value to the "leastCost" variable
        }
    }

System.out.println("The lowest number is: " + lowestNum);
}
```

In this code, I'll end up getting a 0, with priceArray[3] = {2.2, 2.4, 3.3}. If I change:

```
lowestNum = priceArray[i];
```

to

```
lowestNum += priceArray[i];
```

I'll end up getting 3.3, when I should be getting 2.2. Any suggestions for how I can do this?

Comment: Why would you *add*?

Comment: With addition, I know the logic doesn't work at all. It's a beginner mistake on my part. I'm used to adding when doing this with an empty string versus an integer.

Comment: When I run your code, I get 2.2, not 0. As the answers suggest, your code is wrong, but in the case you posted ({2.2, 2.4, 3.3]) it happens to produce the right answer.

Comment: Turns out my Array wasn't storing the values like I thought. Error is in a different part of the code too. Thanks for looking guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (priceArray[i] < priceArray[i - 1])
```

should be replaced with

```
if (priceArray[i] < lowestNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `if` with this:

```
if (priceArray[i] < lowestNum) {
    lowestNum = priceArray[i]; //what I'm trying to do is rewrite this
}
```

As it is, your code is comparing an element of the array with the element just before it. You're not comparing to the already saved lowest value, stored in `lowestNum`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare with the current lowest:

```
for (int i = 1; i < priceArray.length; i++) {
    if (priceArray[i] < lowestNum) {
        lowestNum = priceArray[i]; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Check if your array is not empty before setting the default value.**

**2. Your condition is wrong.** You need to compare the number presently held by "lowestnum" with the next possible candidate until there are no more numbers to check.

```
if(priceArray[i] < lowestNum){
  lowestNum = priceArray[i];
}
```

NOTE: There are more efficient ways (algorithms... lookup "search algorithms") to achieve what you are trying to do and you certainly do not need to program them since they usually already have been program to the best of their possible efficiency for each individual programming language in it's respective STL (Standard Template Library).

**3.** Try to give a little thought to your problems before looking for help. This is really basic and you won't ever learn anything if you ask for a ready solution to any problem you encounter... I recommend you read the first 2 or 3 chapters of any programming book for the language you are interested in learning...

*Hope this helps for now...*

Comment: Unless the array is sorted, there is no more efficient algorithm than a linear scan. Also, I don't see the value of the Java Collections framework (the Java equivalent to STL) for this problem.

Comment: Many configuration exist. For instance, if the array is sorted, binary search can be used which is far more efficient than linear search. Since the poster has not given any explanation as what he intends on using this search method for, anything is possible. The value of an STL is that it's been refined over the years by people interested in making it better and every aspect of memory usage, instruction count, etc. has presumably been taken into account (or at least more than a regular person would take into account)...

Comment: I disagree that "anything is possible". For instance, if the array is known to be sorted, the problem simply goes away: just take the first (or last) element. So we must assume that the array is not guaranteed to be sorted (even if the posted example happens to be). Furthermore, whether or not one can assert that the array is sorted, binary search is the wrong tool (in the one case because it's not needed and in the other case because the preconditions for its use do not hold).

Comment: Actually yeah... in a sorted array the last element would do LOL... but then again there are interesting options using search and sort algorithms depending on what the final use is... for instance if that biggest element is to be constantly accessed it might be better to sort the array once and then as you pointed out pick up the last element... There the importance of that "anything is possible" = "the adequate solution depends on the purpose".

Comment: If the biggest element of an unsorted array is to be repeatedly accessed, then the best solution is to find it once using a linear scan (in O(n) operations) and cache it. Much better than sorting (O(n log n)) and then picking the element directly. You're also assuming that sorting the array won't mess up anything else; it's quite possible that the order is important and sorting cannot be used at all.